# DMA circular input

Tags: dma, hal-library, stm32f4-discovery

I want to copy the same value, say `0.0f`, into a big block of SDRAM through DMA. For example, STM Discovery 429 uses DMA2D for fast screen clearing with the specified `uint32_t color`. I want to do the same for DMA. But I don't see the API to do so with HAL library.

When I call `HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&hdma, srcAddress, dstAddress, dataLength)`, I want to specify that my *srcAddress* (not destination) is a circular buffer with length 1. So it will always transmit the same value across a big chunk of SDRAM.

How can I do so?

Programming board: STM32F429I DISCOVERY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to write the value you want into the first location of the target buffer, then carry out the DMA operation with the source address set to the start of the target buffer, the destination address set to the start of the target buffer plus one and the buffer length set to the length of the target buffer minus one. The DMA operation will then copy the value from the first location to the second, then second to third and so on to the end of the buffer.

It's an old trick from the days of Z80 programming in assembler with the LDIR instruction...

Comment: For some reason, I have to copy the first _two_ values into the target buffer and set the offset of _two_ entities. Besides that, it worked. Thank you for posting this wonderful trick. Another embarrassedly obvious way to achieve this is to set `DmaHandle.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE`. It's available in HAL DMA config and I missed it.